# force exit of an ocaml async program

Tags: asynchronous, ocaml

I'd like to implement the following behavior:

```
let x = 
    try 
       do_some_computation ()
    with
    | Some_error -> exit_my_program ()
in
...
```

Of course, I could raise an exception such as:

```
let exit_my_program () = failwith "...."
```

But, I'd like something like:

```
let exit_my_program () =
    Print.printf "some error message\n";
    exit 1
```

The issue I'm having is that `exit 1` has type `'a Deferred.t` and it's not going to typecheck. I'm wondering if there's an exit function with type `'a` that I could use in this context, or maybe more generally, a function that would force a deferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `Pervasives.exit` is of type `int -> 'a`. I don't know async, so I don't know if it's a good plan to use this function. It's easy to believe it might not be such a good plan if you want things to wind down carefully.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, it seems to do the trick.  However, I'm under the impression that `Async.exit` purposely shadows `Pervasive.exit` (normally you open `Async` everywhere). This leaves me thinking that it's not the best solution. Not sure why though.